# Why does for loop work for a single object but not an array of objects?

Tags: python, arrays, string

Alright, I am scrambling words here and want to store a scrambled array alongside the original array of words.

Initially I create my array:

```
randomwords = ['pepper', 'lightning', 'bored', 'teeth', 'floor', 'special', 'coffee', 'dopamine']
```

Then to scramble:

```
for j in range(len(randomwords)):
    word = randomwords[j] # original
    newword = ''
    for i in range(len(word)):
        newchar = random.choice(word)
        while(newchar in newword):
            newchar = random.choice(word)
        newword = newword[:i]+str(newchar)+newword[i:]
    shuffledwords.append(newword)
```

This works for the first word, or if I just have 1 object in the array, but with multiple Pycharm freezes. I don't know what is going on.

Am I creating an infinite loop somehow?

EDIT **I need to do this manually, not using shuffle**

I am now trying with indices however still have infinite loop:

```
for j in range(len(randomwords)):
    word = randomwords[j] # original
    newword = ''
    indices = []
    for i in range(len(word)):
        newchar = random.choice(word)
        while(word.index(newchar) in indices):
            newchar = random.choice(word)
        indices.append(word.index(newchar))
        newword = newword[:i]+str(newchar)+newword[i:]
    shuffledwords.insert(j, word)
```

Comment: `while(newchar in newword)` looks hinky...

Comment: @StephenRauch putting a break makes the entire for loop not work.

Comment: terminology note: that is a *list* not an array

Comment: Have you considered what happens to words with repeating characters?

Comment: You don't need to use `str` since newchar is already a string.

Comment: If you want to scramble, you can use `random.shuffle` or similar. This looks inefficient and you want to be careful to make sure your distribution is uniform.

Comment: What is happening in the while loop? What is the use of it? If you simply want to do a scrambling, the most Pythonic way is ```random.shuffle()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you!

```
import random
randomwords = ['pepper', 'lightning', 'bored', 'teeth', 'floor', 'special', 'coffee', 'dopamine']

def scrmble(var):
    scrbled=var[:]
    random.shuffle(scrbled)
    return (scrbled)


newlist = scrmble(randomwords)

print(randomwords, newlist)
```

Comment: you can always change the print to return a longer dictionary with shuffled list.

Answer (score 1):

I think you  do have an infinite loop.

```
newchar = random.choice(word)
```

randomly selects a letter in `word`.

If `word` contains duplicate letters, then `newword` will contain all the letters in `word` before your `for i in range(len(word))` loop is done. That will create an infinite loop  with `while (newchar in newword)`

Consider "pepper":

Imagine in the first 3 iterations you select "p","r" and "e". The `for i` loop is not yet done, but `newchar = random.choice(word)` will always select a character already in `newword`

I would try creating a list of the letters in the word you're scrambling, and then randomly removing one letter at a time from that list, until it is empty.

================================================================

Late edit, but wanted to show 1 way to do this manually....

```
import random

randomwords = ['pepper', 'lightning', 'bored', 'teeth', 
               'floor', 'special', 'coffee', 'dopamine']
shuffledwords = []

for j in range(len(randomwords)):
    word = randomwords[j] # original word to scramble

    newword = '' #scrambled word
    num_letters = len(word) #original number of letters in word

    for i in range(num_letters):
        # pick raandom letter from those still in word
        curr_idx = random.randrange(len(word))
        newchar = word[curr_idx]
        #print (newchar)

        # remove chosen letter from original word
        if curr_idx == 0:
            word = word[1:]
        elif curr_idx == len(word)-1:
            word = word[0:-1]
        else:
            word = word[0:curr_idx] + word[curr_idx+1:]

        # Add chosen letter to scrambled word
        newword = newword[:i]+str(newchar)+newword[i:]
    #print(newword)
    shuffledwords.append(newword)
```

Comment: I think `word.index(newchar)` gives same problem as before. When the same letter appears multiple times, this will always pick out either the first or last appearance of the letter. So, with "pepper", each time an index corresponding to a 'p' is selected, word.index('p') will return 0. You need to actively maintain a list of chosen/unchosen letters/indices and quit when it is either of same length as the word or empty.

Answer (score 0):

This will scramble the words and all the char inside each word.

```py
import random
randomwords = ['pepper', 'lightning', 'bored', 'teeth', 'floor', 'special', 'coffee', 'dopamine']
randomwords = random.sample(randomwords,len(randomwords))
new_word = ""
for word in randomwords:
    word1 = random.sample(word, len(word))
    new_word = new_word + ''.join(word1) + " "
print(new_word)
```

Result: "gnhinligt folor lesacpi prpepe ediaopmn hteet ecffoe edorb"